# contenttype.model_class() is NoneType

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have this in models.py for a shoppingcart app:

```
def get_all_models():
    tup = []
    for ct in ContentType.objects.filter(app_label__in=['shoppingcart','products','productoptions']):
        if ct is not None:
            mclass = ct.model_class()
            if mclass is not None:
                tup.append((mclass.__module__+'.'+mclass.__name__,mclass.__name__))
    return tuple(tup)

class ConditionSet(models.Model):
    model_name      = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = get_all_models()) 
    model_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    operator        = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=OPERATORS)
    val             = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    evaluation      = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    def get_all_models():
        tup = []
        for ct in ContentType.objects.filter(app_label__in=['shoppingcart','products','productoptions']):
            if ct is not None:
                mclass = ct.model_class()
                if mclass is not None:
                    tup.append((mclass.__module__+'.'+mclass.__name__,mclass.__name__))
        return tuple(tup)
    def evaluate(self):
        app_label = str(self.model_name.split('.')[0])
        model_name = str(self.model_name.split('.')[2])
        model = get_model(app_label= app_label, model_name = model_name)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_attribute
```

in admin.py i only registered the models

i found my def get_all_models() produce two different set of output, when running from shell
i have this

> > > get_all_models()
> > >       (('shoppingcart.models.Cart', 'Cart'), ('shoppingcart.models.CartItem', 'CartItem'), ('shoppingcart.models.CartRule', 'CartRule'), ('products.models.CasesAccessory', 'CasesAccessory'), ('productoptions.models.Coating', 'Coating'), ('shoppingcart.models.ConditionSet', 'ConditionSet'), ('products.models.Eyeglass', 'Eyeglass'), ('products.models.GiftVoucher', 'GiftVoucher'), ('productoptions.models.Lens', 'Lens'), ('productoptions.models.Prescription', 'Prescription'), ('products.models.Readingglass', 'Readingglass'), ('products.models.Sunglass', 'Sunglass'), ('productoptions.models.Tint', 'Tint'), ('productoptions.models.Vision', 'Vision'))

where as when its called to populate choices, i loose the first choice,
the first option that is , conetenttype cart gives model_class() as None, while it finds the model_class() when working on shell ?  need some explanation .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is getting executed when Django validates it's models. Hence, `Cart` probably has not been validated yet and it's model class is `None`.

I suggest not setting choices in the model definition, I've had a few troubles with it before. Instead, I recommend dynamically populating them sometime later, e.g. when you instantiate a form.